# how do you evaluate the p-adic modular form E_p-1 in the region |j|<1

Tags: p-adic-analysis, modular-forms, nt.number-theory

### background/motivation

let *E<sub>k</sub>* denote the modular form of level one and weight *k* with *q*-expansion given by $E_k(q)=1- \frac{2k}{b_k}\sum_n \sigma_{k-1}(n)q^n$ where σ<sub>*i*</sub>   is the [divisor sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) and *b<sub>k</sub>* is the *k*-th [bernoulli number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). for *k = p – 1* the the denominators of this series don't contain any powers of  *p* and hence by the *q*-expansion principle *E<sub>p–1</sub>* defines a modular form over ℤ*<sub>p</sub>*. that is,  *E<sub>p–1</sub>* ∈ *H*<sup>0</sup>(*X*<sub>0</sub>(1),  ℤ*<sub>p</sub>* ⊗ ω<sup>⊗k</sup>) where *X*<sub>0</sub>(1) is the compactified modular curve for the full modular group, and ω is the pushforward of the canonical bundle on the universal elliptic curve over  ℤ.

now i can use *p*-adic uniformisation to evaluate *E<sub>p–1</sub>* via its *q*-expansion at elliptic curves with *j*-invariant satisfying | *j* | > 1; in concrete terms this means formally inverting the power series for 1/j(*q*), and then evaluating *E<sub>*p*–1</sub>(*q*) on the result.

i don't suppose one should expect to get a well-defined value in ℂ<sub>*p*</sub> for *E<sub>p–1</sub>* evaluated at elliptic curves for which | *j* | < 1 (as you would for an modular form over ℂ) since this would mean choosing a non-vanishing differential on the universal elliptic curve over ℤ*<sub>p</sub>*. the *norm* |*E<sub>p–1</sub>* |, however, *is* well defined, since any two choices of basis for the canonial bundle on a given elliptic curve can only differ by a unit.

of course the context i am interested in is when |*E<sub>p–1</sub>*| is used to define the "overconvergent" region of the modular curve. this is (roughly) defined as the region of the $j$-line satisfying |*E<sub>p–1</sub>*|>*r* for |*r*|<1. this region will (always) include part of the |*j*|<1 region.  in order to understand what |*E<sub>p–1</sub>*|>*r* "means" in concrete terms, i was hoping to numerically compare |*E<sub>4</sub>*| and |j| for some specific ℂ<sub>*p*</sub>-values of *j* near 0 (for primes *p* = 5, 7, 11 etc. for which *j* = 0 is supersingular).

anyway, my question is:

> > how can i *explicitly* evaluate |*E<sub>p–1</sub>*| at elliptic curves  with | *j* | < 1?

Comment:  Quick side note: j=0 isn't supersingular at p=7, right? Isn't it only the primes where p = -1 mod 3? I'm afraid I have nothing substantive to add.

Comment: oops, yep right you are, i meant p=2,5,11

Comment: This comment is sort of tangentially related to your question, since here $p=3$.  Mazur, Tate and I wrote a paper http://wstein.org/papers/pheight/ on computing $p$-adic heights.  The main problem we ran into was evaluating the $p$-adic modular form $E_2$ efficiently, and we solved the problem using Monsky-Washnitzer cohomology.  A lot of the paper is also about studying a notion of "log convergence" that Mazur and Tate got really interested in for some reason.  

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One has $j  = E_4^3/\Delta$.  In the region $|j|\leq 1$, one is parameterizing elliptic curves with good reduction, and so $\Delta$ is a unit.  Thus $|j| = |E_4|^3$.  This will help you
when $p = 5$.

When $p = 7,$ one can write $j = 1278 + E_6^2/\Delta,$ hence $|E_6|^2 = | j - 1728|$ on
the region $|j| \leq 1$.

For $p = 11$, these sort of explicit computations are harder (but maybe not much; see 
the added material below), because there are two supersingular $j$-invariants.  But the $p = 5$ and 7 cases will already be illustrative.

In the case when $p = 2$, I wrote something about this once, which appeared in an
appendix an article by Fernando Gouvea in a Park City proceedings volume.  A slightly
butchered version (missing figures, among other things) can be found on my
[web-page](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~emerton/preprints.html) (near
the bottom).  You might also look at the papers of Buzzard--Calegari
for related computations, as well as my thesis (available on my web-page) and later
work by Kilford and Buzzard--Kilford.  (There is, or at least once was, a cottage industry
based on combining these sorts of explicit computations with some more theoretical
estimates, to compute information about slopes of overconvergent $p$-adic modular forms
for various small primes $p$.)

Added in response to the comment below: For $p = 11$, one has 
$E_{10}  = E_4 E_6,$
so $E_{10}^6 = j^2(j-1728)^3 \Delta^5,$ and so when $|j| \leq 1,$ one has
$|E_{10}|^6  = |j|^2|j-1728|^3.$ Perhaps this will help?

Comment: thanks for that emerton, i'm familiar with the work you mention, actually it was p=11 that was my motivation; lawren smithline's paper "bounding slopes" (http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0705.3614) relates j and E_p-1 for all the p such that there is only one supersingular curve. i haven't been make that method work for p=11, and so i was hoping to do some explicit computer calculations to see if that might give some sort of hint as how to proceed...

Comment: I added something about $p = 11$ to my answer, which may help.

Comment: No worries. Your "thanks heaps" made me wonder if you are Australian, and then I looked at your profile and saw that you're at Melbourne.  It's nice to see that p-adic modular forms are still alive and well in the halls of Richard Berry.  

Comment: I think Kilford did something with p=11 recently (computing a basis for overconvergent forms: the point is that you can use both positive and negative powers of T, if T is a parameter on the annulus of ordinary forms).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion kevin--it was actually kilford's paper that got me thinking about this stuff. matthew's answer is exactly what i wanted. to generalise it to arbitrary p: express E_{p-1} as a polynomial in E4 and E6 (homogeneous with respect to the usual grading), take the sixth power and then make the substitutions E4^3 |-> j*delta, E6^2 |-> (j-1728)*delta; now you have a polynomial in j and delta.

Comment: @Max the link in [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14214/how-do-you-evaluate-the-p-adic-modular-form-e-p-1-in-the-region-j1/14220#comment24843_14220) is broken, here's a replacement: https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.3614